# Postgres - CREATE FOREIGN TABLE based on other table

Tags: postgresql, foreign-table

I'm looking way to simplify `CREATE FOREIGN` command, so do need to specify all columns and types.

What I'm doing now (using file_fdw server):

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE temp_table_csv 
(id integer, name text)
SERVER csv_log_server
OPTIONS ( filename 'path_to_file.csv', format 'csv');
```

What I would like to do:

```
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE temp_table_csv 
(like example_table)
SERVER csv_log_server
OPTIONS ( filename 'path_to_file.csv', format 'csv');
```

Using `LIKE` or similar command so Postgres can read structure out of there
But it says "like is not supported"

Comment: I have not used it, but `import foreign schema` limited to a single table seems to be what you want: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-importforeignschema.html

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name  - but this seems doesnt work with file_fdw extension - Ive got this:
 "file_fdw" does not support IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA